# What docker network should chaincode containers stay in?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I have a fabric network setup that works through a docker *overlay* network. When I execute `docker network inspect fab_overlay_net` the chaincode containers are there along with the peer and orderer containers.

My question is whether the chaincode containers should be isolated from the rest of the containers in another network and if so, how can I do that (the chaincode containers are created from the peer container)?

Comment: Trying to understand the concern: are you thinking about security of the chaincode container?

Comment: Yes, is it a problem from a security standpoint if the chaincode containers stay in the same overlay network with the peers and orderers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not believe that your chaincode may be on a different network of peers. I tried but when the peer tries to communicate with the chaincode he looks for it on the same network. By cons, I think the orderer may be on another network.